# Displaying image on point hover in Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

Plotly allows you to display text fields when hovering over a point on a scatterplot. Is it possible to instead display an image associated with each point when the user hovers over or clicks on it? I am mostly just using the web interface, but I could instead push my `ggplot` from R.

Comment: Have you tried `ggiraph` package?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58897330/hover-image-in-plotly-r-chart-in-shiny-app/59032642#59032642) you can find an example using `shiny`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Images on hover is now available by Plotly lib. Here is a sample:

[image]

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output, no_update
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

# Small molcule drugbank dataset
# Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/dash-sample-apps/main/apps/dash-drug-discovery/data/small_molecule_drugbank.csv'
data_path = 'datasets/small_molecule_drugbank.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=0, index_col=0)

fig = go.Figure(data=[
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["LOGP"],
        y=df["PKA"],
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(
            colorscale='viridis',
            color=df["MW"],
            size=df["MW"],
            colorbar={"title": "Molecular<br>Weight"},
            line={"color": "#444"},
            reversescale=True,
            sizeref=45,
            sizemode="diameter",
            opacity=0.8,
        )
    )
])

# turn off native plotly.js hover effects - make sure to use
# hoverinfo="none" rather than "skip" which also halts events.
fig.update_traces(hoverinfo="none", hovertemplate=None)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(title='Log P'),
    yaxis=dict(title='pkA'),
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(255,255,255,0.1)'
)

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id="graph-basic-2", figure=fig, clear_on_unhover=True),
    dcc.Tooltip(id="graph-tooltip"),
])


@app.callback(
    Output("graph-tooltip", "show"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "bbox"),
    Output("graph-tooltip", "children"),
    Input("graph-basic-2", "hoverData"),
)
def display_hover(hoverData):
    if hoverData is None:
        return False, no_update, no_update

    # demo only shows the first point, but other points may also be available
    pt = hoverData["points"][0]
    bbox = pt["bbox"]
    num = pt["pointNumber"]

    df_row = df.iloc[num]
    img_src = df_row['IMG_URL']
    name = df_row['NAME']
    form = df_row['FORM']
    desc = df_row['DESC']
    if len(desc) > 300:
        desc = desc[:100] + '...'

    children = [
        html.Div([
            html.Img(src=img_src, style={"width": "100%"}),
            html.H2(f"{name}", style={"color": "darkblue"}),
            html.P(f"{form}"),
            html.P(f"{desc}"),
        ], style={'width': '200px', 'white-space': 'normal'})
    ]

    return True, bbox, children


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

More info: https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/tooltip

Comment: Is it safe to say the that your approach only loads and shows the images on the `on hover` event, while using purely a [Adavance Hover Template](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#advanced-hover-template) would load all images to then show `on hover`?

Comment: @EduardoReis using the customs callbacks to display images will only get the REST image when the mouse is over the graphic node. I will suggest you to test advance hover template in debug mode to check if it will load all the images.  It don't seems to be a good approach to get all the images, I never put it to prove. When you get this answer may you could share the results with community

Comment: Link massively helps!

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, there is no *easy* way to display images on hover on plotly graphs at the moment.

If you are willing to learn some javascript, plotly's [embed API](https://github.com/plotly/Embed-API) allows you to customize hover (as well as click) interactivity.

Here is an [example](http://etpinard.github.io/plotly-dashboards/hover-images/) of a custom hover interaction showing images on top of a plotly graph. The javascript source code can be found [here](https://github.com/etpinard/plotly-dashboards/tree/master/hover-images).