# Dynamic plot with hovering popups in R

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

I am trying to find a way to have a dynamic plot (for the moment I use plotly) in which if you keep the mouse over a certain point it is calling a routine which is showing something, e.g. a photo that is referring to that specific data point. An example is to have the MNIST data-set clustered in 2 dimensions (e.g. using t-SNE) and when you go over the points with the pointer you see the actual digit which stays for that point.

Comment: I would recommend to provide some reproducible data and a screenshot of your desired result. Some of this just sounds like basic mouse hover pop-up info but you're talking about photos and using some terms that make it a little unclear to me what you want.

Comment: as I understand you would like to have something like [this](http://etpinard.xyz/plotly-dashboards/hover-images/). Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445198/displaying-image-on-point-hover-in-plotly) to a similar question. I am keen to hear if things have improved for R users.

Comment: Thank you, that is the nearest thing I could find! Nonetheless, I think I must code it from that scratch because I do not have an archive of specific images but only the MNIST dataset (which needs a specific function to produce an image).